# python pandas how to combine the pandas with the same column value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

convert this frame:

```
1, 2
----
a, g
a, a
a, j
d, b
c, e
```

into:

```
1, 2
----
a, g,a,j
d, b
c, e
```

what can I do, can I use groupby? what other methods?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply` function `join`:

```
df.columns = list('AB')
print (df)
   A  B
0  a  g
1  a  a
2  a  j
3  d  b
4  c  e

df = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
print (df)
   A      B
0  a  g,a,j
1  c      e
2  d      b
```

Answer (score 1):

`pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table('B', 'A', aggfunc=','.join)

A
a    g,a,j
c        e
d        b
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Comment: Even better and shorter :)

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways but one of the ways can be like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# df = pd.read_clipboard()
df2 = df.copy()
df2.columns=['col1','col2']
df2=df2.groupby('col1',as_index=False).sum()
df2.col2 = df2.col2.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(.)',r'\1,', x) if len(x)>1 else x)
df2
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Lainey Check jezrael's answer. Much more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep g,a,j as a python list then you can use apply to a function that returns either a list or a scalar depending on the number of elements:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('aaadc'), 'B':list('gajbe')})

df = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda s: list(s) if len(s)>1 else s.iloc[0]).reset_index()
print (df)
```

Outputs:

```
   A          B
0  a  [g, a, j]
1  c          e
2  d          b
```