# Python Pandas: Get index of rows which column matches certain value (max)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I am trying to get the index of the row that has the maximum value in the column '% Renewable'. This is the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'% Renewable': [np.NaN, 12, np.NaN, 11, 17, 62, 18, 15, np.NaN, 2, np.NaN, np.NaN, 6, np.NaN, 70]},
   index=['China', 'United States', 'Japan', 'United Kingdom', 'Russian Federation', 'Canada', 'Germany', 'India', 'France', 'South Korea', 'Italy', 'Spain', 'Iran', 'Australia', 'Brazil'])
```

I get the maximum value using the max method:

```
 df[['% Renewable']].max()
```

'70' is the maximum value and it is associated to the index key 'Brazil'. But which command line does return 'Brazil'? My try:

```
df[df['% Renewable'] == float(70)].index.tolist()
```

Unfortunately, I get an empty list. Any idea?

Comment: You need `print (df['% Renewable'].idxmax())`

Comment: @jezrael how to get both? id as well as value?

Comment: Then use `loc` - `print (df.loc[df['% Renewable'].idxmax()])`

Comment: @jezrael thanks :). Can you answer this one better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236061/python-pandas-how-to-combine-the-pandas-with-the-same-column-value

Comment: thank you for tip. I answer it.

Comment: @jezrael :D. I knew you might be knowing some better trick :P

Comment: @Antonio Serrano - If duplicates answer does not help or need something else, be free modify question and give me a comment, I can reopen your question.

Comment: It works! Many thanks @jezrael :)